# ExactTarget - Importing data from XML file to a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are evaluating some of the ways to import data from a XML file and load data into a data extension.

We found a Data Extract activity (refer below link) to convert the   XML to CSV data and then using an import activity to import data from CSV file to a data extension. But this activity only deals with Simple XMl files.
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/convert_xml/

Is there any other way that this use case can be executed in ET?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? i got same issue now

Answer (score 1):

You will need to contact your ET representative  to do it within ET proper for complex XML.  There is probably a data extract that already exists to do what you need, which just needs to be added to your account, but an ET Data Architect would want to see your data before making that determination.

There are many free XML to CSV converters out there for download, which you also may want to consider.    I've relied on those on occasion to do what you are asking.